# Rotating Right Bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to rotate right with the following conditions :

```
 /*
  * rotateRight - Rotate x to the right by n
  *   Can assume that 0 <= n <= 31
  *   Legal ops: ~ & ^ | + << >>
  *   Max ops: 25
  *   Rating: 3
 */
```

This is what I thought of so far :

```
return (x >> n) | (x << (32+ (~n+1))
```

But this gives me an error when I used the tester:

```
ERROR: Test rotateRight(-2147483648[0x80000000],1[0x1]) failed...
  ...Gives -1073741824[0xc0000000]. Should be 1073741824[0x40000000]
```

I've been staring at this for a while, and not sure what to do (either change my approach and/or change my algorithm) Please advise bit geniuses!!

Comment: In your example, `rotateRight(0x87654321,4) = 0x76543218`, that looks like a *left* rotation to me.  Likewise, your error result is the opposite rotation from the "should be" value.

Comment: That's actually a typo sorry..disregard that

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your exact code I made it into a program as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t rotateRight( uint32_t x, uint32_t n )
{
    return (x >> n) | (x << (32+ (~n+1)) );
}


int main(){

    uint32_t value = 0x80000000;
    uint32_t newValue;

    newValue = rotateRight( value, 1 );

    printf( "orig: 0x%8.8x\n", value );
    printf( "new:  0x%8.8x\n", newValue );

    return 0;
}
```

When run this gave the results:

```
orig: 0x80000000
new:  0x40000000
```

Note: If I replace the `uint32_t` with `int` then I get the 0xC0000000 result as you do. When dealing with bits it is best to use unsigned types. I always use unsigned types for everything except the few cases where I specifically want signed.

[Edit: Here is a new code block where it is accepting int values]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rotateRight( int x, int n )
{
    return (int)((unsigned)x >> n) | ((unsigned)x << (32+ (~n+1)) );
}

int main(){

    int value = -2147483648;
    int newValue;

    newValue = rotateRight( value, 1 );

    printf( "orig: %d\n", value );
    printf( "new:  %d\n", newValue );

    return 0;
}
```

This gives the output:

```
orig: -2147483648
new:  1073741824
```

Comment: Yeah, I know but that's just how the tester is going to be testing my program so there's nothing I can do about that. Thank you for your answre tho!

Comment: In that case I would recommend internally changing the types to unsigned ints in the calculation and returning it back as an int. 
    `int rotateRight( int x, int n )
    {
        return (int)((unsigned)x >> n) | ((unsigned)x << (32+ (~n+1)) );
    }`

Comment: I've added a different version of the code that uses `int` values as input and output. Hope this helps

Comment: @waterjuice Your alg works fine.  The outer int cast on the return isn't strictly required.  I also tested your program with some "harder" values of 1 and 3.  They are also fine.